Pytest_error_not operable
Below is the error that I'm facing. Can someone help me to fix this issue?
I'm trying to automate:
'pytest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

How to fix this issue and resolved this error.
Please help me as O'm doing automation for one website.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
